# Centering AChartEngine Dial chart

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

I'm totally lost here. It should be dead simple but I can't center a Dial chart from AChartEngine in my layout.

I am following the Demo example to the letter but it still does not work for me and I'm out of ideas!

My last layout test follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TEST-TEST" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graph1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I get a perfectly centered "TEST-TEST" text and the dial to the right of that but around 55% of the screen size, clearly to the left of where it should be centered. It's actually not getting clipped to the second layout because of the margins (I am using the demo ones too).

If I change the graph for another textview I get it perfectly centered as expected.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: I can add a new bit of interesting evidence here. I migrated BudgetChart demo into my app. Same code AND same layout as used in the demo. The chart shows completely to the left, half chart get's clipped as its drawn outside from the screen. The only difference here is that the layout lives in a frame shown with a SectionsPagerAdapter, could aChartEngine have problems finding it way around on a layout inside a fragment?

Comment: More potentially relevant info. The call used in the demo to add the view 'layout_eeg1.addView(view_eeg1); //, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));' gets flagged as the constants are deprecated. I'm building against Android 4.2. IF I use something like LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200) it does get centered. This is not a solution though as I'm fix the layout size and making it impossible to work for several devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this call:

```
renderer.setInScroll(true);
```

This will help in cases when the chart view is added to a custom layout.